# jquery change image without showing background

Tags: jquery

I use jquery to change one image to another while clicking buttons. The code:

```
var toChange = $('#toChange');
            toChange.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                toChange.attr('src','1.jpg');
                toChange.fadeIn();
            });
```

but when the button is clicked the image, which is currently shown, fades out, then for some seconds background is shown, and only then the second image fades in. How can it be done to avoid showing background?

Comment: you may have to wait for the image to load before calling fade in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var toChange = $('#toChange');
toChange.fadeOut('fast')
        .attr('src','1.jpg')
        .fadeIn('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want toggle two images with fadein, another temporary element should be used, and do fadeIn before fadeOut. There are three steps:

1. load image (U can skip this step, it just for some image load slowly)
2. fadeIn new image on top of old one
3. remove old image

Call next step on each callback:

```
var el = $('<img src="'+src+'" />').hide().appendTo($('.box'));

el.one('load', function() {
    el.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $('.box img').first().remove();
    });
})
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/9zx32cg6/